# Flutter: About changing the version of packages such as flutterfire

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I am making an application with flutter and firebase.
Regarding packages (libraries),
I heard that various flutterfire packages have been upgraded recently.

For flutter I think that package management is done by listing the package names we want to install in the pubspec.yaml file.
What should I do when the package is updated?

In the upper right corner of the screen
pub upgrade
There is a link saying, but it seems that pressing this does not change the version of each package to the latest version.
Do I have to regularly check for updates myself and manually rewrite this?

pub upgrade
What is the function in the end?
Where should I look to find out?

Another question. At the moment, the firebase_storage package of the pubspec.yaml file is described as follows.

```
  firebase_storage:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/danysz/flutterfire.git
      ref: master
      path: packages/firebase_storage
```

In order to use the method "listAll" to get all the data of firebase_storage like this
I've been taught how to write it on another site before.
When I update other packages of flutterfire in pubspec.yaml file,
pub get
When I do, I get an error in the firebase_storage part.

However, if I specify the latest version of firebase_storage as below, the listAll method cannot be used.

```
firebase_storage: ^4.0.0
```

After all, if I do not update the package in the pubspec.yaml file,
the app works at the moment (all can be obtained by the "listAll" method),
But I don't think there is an option to never update the pubspec.yaml file at all.
How can I get the package version up to date and use the listAll method?

Answer (score 1):

`listAll` method is still not added to the `firebase_storage` plugin, therefore even if you upgrade to `firebase_storage 4.0.0` you can't use `listAll`.

The following url https://github.com/danysz/flutterfire, is the repository of the person who implemented `listAll`, but the pull request is still not merged. You can follow it here:

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/pull/232

Therefore if you want to use `listAll` then keep using the same versions of the other firebase products and keep using the above url.

---

Regarding updating plugins:

> To upgrade to a new version of the package, for example to use new features in that package, run `flutter pub upgrade` (Upgrade dependencies in IntelliJ or Android Studio) to retrieve the highest available version of the package that is allowed by the version constraint specified in `pubspec.yaml`. Note that this is a different command from `flutter upgrade` or `flutter update-packages`, which both update Flutter itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

We don't know when the listAll method will eventually be implemented, right?
I just have to wait for it or do it myself using the methodchannel and rewrite the code with it when the listAll method is implemented, right?

Comment: It's already done here https://github.com/danysz/flutterfire